# Вывод tv поля, Modx Revo

Tags: modx

У ресурса имеется tv поле с типом ввода "**Множественный список**".

В возможных значениях прописал: **@SELECT pagetitle, id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent=18**.

В ресурсе вывод поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока все как хочется. В типе вывода у меня Разделитель, и выбрал "**Запятая**", следовательно желательный результат в голове выглядит так: **11,12,13,14,15**. Но на сайте это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где я делаю ошибку, что не так?

Comment: Вам что надо выводить id или само название? если название то уберите id из запроса, и покажите как выводите полученный список

Comment: Нужно вывести в виде 11,12,13,14,15, а не 11||12||13||14||15 Цифры через запятую, я в вопросе написал. Нужно вместо || чтобы была запятая

Comment: Похоже на вывод с дефолтным разделителем. Вы удалите все внутри поля, сохраните ресурс, потом еще что-то выберите,сохраните и выведите на странице, кстати, как выводите?

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться модификатором вывода **replace**

```
[[*tvName:replace=`||==,`]]
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).